# C++ Array to one Int variable

Tags: c++, arrays, string, hex, decimal

I am curently working on one project, it's a converter... i am currently looking at Decimal to Hexadecimal. The code so far looks like this:

```
int rest;
int arr[50];
int i;
cout << N << " in decimal after conversation ";
while (N>0){
rest=N%16;
if (rest>9){
    switch (rest){
    case 10:
        arr[i]='A';
        break;
    case 11:
        arr[i]='B';
        break;
    case 12:
        arr[i]='C';
        break;
    case 13:
        arr[i]='D';
        break;
    case 14:
        arr[i]='E';
        break;
    case 15:
        arr[i]='F';
        break;
    }
}
else {
    arr[i]=rest;
}
N=N/16;
i+=i;
}
cout<<arr;
return 1;
```

It's in function so dont be troubeled about the return 1...
my Question is:
is there any way possible to pull the whole array (for example containig [4,2,K,8] into one single variable? In the same exact order!

> *EDIT*

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaand I'm back :D 
i made a few changes to the program and now it is working and it goes like this:

```
int DecToHex(long long N)       
{
int rest;                                           
string s="";                   
while (N>0){                
rest=N%16;            
if (rest>9){      
    switch (rest){     
    case 10:                
        s="A"+s;           
        break;
    case 11:
        s="B"+s;
        break;
    case 12:
        s="C"+s;
        break;
    case 13:
        s="D"+s;
        break;
    case 14:
        s="E"+s;
        break;
    case 15:
        s="F"+s;
        break;
        }
}
else {
    s = char(rest + 48) + s;
    }
N=N/16;
}
     if (s == "")
         cout << "0";
     else
         cout << s;
return 1;
}
```

any idea how i could convert hexadecimal number to binary? the hexadecimal can be in string but the binary needs to be in    int.
the structure of the program shoud be simmiliar to the this one of mine. 
bud thnak's to everyone for the help!

Comment: Have you considered using `std::string` directly instead trying to build and convert your array?

Comment: i would prefer to write it without the "std::" because the whole program should be without them (don't asky me why because i don't know)

Comment: In addition to the above comment, you're putting characters into your array but then you do `arr[i]=rest;`. That should probably be `arr[i] = '0' + rest;`

Comment: That whole switch can also be replaced. Values `10`-`15` (which are obviously consecutive) correspond to characters `'A'`-`'F'` (which are also consecutive)

Comment: @Kevin: whereas `'0'`, , `'9'` is guarantied to be consecutive, it is not the case for `'A'`, .., `'F'`.

Comment: In your example, you have `'K'`, but that is not in your `switch` statement.  Please clarify.

Comment: @Jarod42 You're right in general. In ASCII they are consecutive.

Comment: You could use a simple array lookup:  `static const char digits[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";  cout << "Digit of 13 is: " << digits[13] << "\n";`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there any way possible to pull the whole array (for example containig [4,2,K,8] into one single variable?

You could use a `std::string` and pretend that it is one single variable but it is only an enhanced version of an array of `char`s.

BTW, couple of points that are unrelated to the above question.

1. You can simplify the `switch` statement. This was pointed out in a comment by @Kevin.
2. Use of `arr[i]=rest;` is wrong. It needs to be `arr[i]=rest+'0';`. This was pointed out in a comment by @scohe001.

Here's an updated version of the loop:

```
while ( N > 0 ) {
   rest = N%16;
   if (rest > 9){
      arr[i] = 'A' + rest - 10;
   }
   else {
      arr[i] = '0' + rest;
   }
   N = N/16;
   i += i;
}
```

You can make that still simpler by using the suggestion by @Jarod:

```
char const* hex_letters = "0123456789ABCDEF";
while ( N > 0 ) {
   rest = N%16;
   arr[i] = hex_letters[rest];
   N = N/16;
   i += i;
}
```

Comment: `"0123456789ABCDEF"[rest]` to really portable.

Comment: @Jarod42, of course. Much better than my first suggestion.